# Using document.writeln with input form in Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, input

I'm trying to input a form with Javascript. On the form, if the dropdown selection is a certain selection then specific form fields will appear below.

Here is the code I currently have, but it doesn't seem to work, I am guessing `document.writeln` is not the proper method. If I add an alert to see if it is pulling the selection it works, so something with adding the form in is failing. After the `document.writeln` the alert doesn't even come up anymore?

```
<script language="javascript">
  var HelpTopic = document.getElementById('type');
  HelpTopic.onchange=function() {
    if(HelpTopic.value == "Analytics") {
      alert("Congrats");
      document.writeln('\<li\>
        \<label for\=\"confirm\"\>Input name*\<\/label\>
        \<input type\=\"text\" name\=\"inputs\" id\=\"names\" required \/\>
        \<\/li\>');
    } else {
      alert("Fails");
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't span a string over multiple lines in JS. You need something like this:

```
document.writeln('\<li\>' +
  '\<label for\=\"confirm\"\>Input name*\<\/label\>' +
  '\<input type\=\"text\" name\=\"inputs\" id\=\"names\" required \/\>' +
'\<\/li\>');
```

*EDIT*: You don't need so much escaping. This will work just as well:

```
document.writeln(
  '<li>' +
   '<label for="confirm">Input name*</label> ' +
   '<input type="text" name="inputs" id="names" required />' +
  '</li>');
```

Comment: I would not use `document.writeln` after the document is loaded. Use dom methods instead.

Answer (score 1):

To properly add list item to some list have such code instead:

```
var oList = document.getElementById("MyList");
var oItem = document.createElement("li");
oItem.innerHTML = "<label for='confirm'>Input name*</label><input type='text' name='inputs' required />";
oList.appendChild(oItem);
```

This will add item to list with ID `MyList`.

Answer (score 0):

just a quick note, multi line strings are supported in javascript like this

```
'<li>\
  <label for="confirm">Input name*</label>\
  <input type="text" name="inputs" id="names" required />\
</li>'
```

I agree with Shadow Wizard, that would be the best way to append a list

Answer (score 0):

The way you're trying to dynamically modify the "onChange" (missing capital C) seems to have trouble with Chrome

Also, you cant split a string over multiple lines the way you did

The following code should work, notice I added "onChange=myfunc();" to the select:

```
<select id=type onChange=myfunc();>";
<option value=Other>Other</option>
<option value=Analytics>Analytics</option>
</select>


<script language="javascript">
function myfunc()
{
var HelpTopic = document.getElementById('type');

if(HelpTopic.value == "Analytics") {
    alert("Congrats");
    document.write('<li><label for="confirm">Input name*</label><input type="text" name="inputs" id="names" required></li>');
} else {
    alert("Fails");
}

}
</script>
```